# query in sql server for retrieving rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table that contains the following 4 columns:

- id
- name
- lastname
- phone

I want to write a stored procedure that gets an `id` as parameter, and then gets the name of that `id` and then use that `name` to get all the rows that their name is equal to the names that i found in last step!
here it is my query, i know it's wrong but i'm new to sql commands:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllNames
@id int
AS
    select name as Name from Users where id = @id
    -- i don't how to retrieve the names that are equal to Name
select * from Users where name = Name
```

can you correct my query and help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable `@name` where you can store the name....

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllNames
    @id int
    AS
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(50);
      select  @name =name from Users where id = @id;
      select * from Users where name =  @name;
```

I have just provide above solution as per your question style but I strongly recommend you to use JOIN in given scenario in following way:

```
  SELECT b.name FROM Users a
                INNER JOIN Users b
                ON a.name = b.name
   WHERE a.id = @id
```

Comment: tanx a lot,i tried to accept the solution but it bumped into a pop up that i have to wait for 8 minutes:)

Comment: Why would you declare a variable instead of using a simple JOIN query?

Comment: @Sashenka : I just go with OP's question....I've not offer my solution since OP is stuck on that part....Now, OP know how to use variable in future...

Comment: why wouldn't i?joining makes a new table in ram,i know that's temporary but i think this way is more optimized:)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to downvote this solution but I hope this will be done by others so that other readers can see that this accepted answer is rather absurd.

Comment: @miracle173 : As I have already stated that I have only followed  OP's question style but I strongly recommend to use JOIN here as Winfield provides.....

Comment: I wouldn't downvote it since it is a valid answer even if it is absurd. Lolcoder, you should edit your answer and mention that a JOIN is better to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @Sashenka : I followed your suggestion and updated my answer as it created much confusion about best solution.....Thanx for suggestion....

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT by_name.name FROM Users AS by_id
  join Users AS by_name ON by_id.name = by_name.name
  where id = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name in (SELECT name from users where id = @id)
```

This would handle the case where there are multiple records with the ID. If ID is a primary key, then you can replace the `IN` operator with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllNames
@Id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Users WHERE [Name] IN (SELECT [Name] FROM Users WHERE Id = @Id)
END
```